# Angular 12 - Deploy Angular Application problem with "base" tag

Tags: angular

In my Angular 12 application I have defined in the "package.json" file this Angular Cli command for deploy in the production environment:

```
"scripts": {
"build_PROD": "ng build --base-href=/myapp/ --configuration production",
},
```

If you run locally the command:

```
ng build --base-href=/myapp/ --configuration production
```

Everything works fine, and when I go to check the "index.html" file I see that it has been generated correctly:

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="/myapp/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<style>html{font-family:sans-serif;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%}@media print{*,:after,:before{background:transparent!important;color:#000!important;box-shadow:none!important;text-shadow:none!important}}:after,:before{box-sizing:border-box}html{font-size:10px;-webkit-tap-highlight-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)}body{font-family:Univers,Arial,sans-serif;font-size:14px;line-height:1.42857143;color:#222;background-color:#fff}body,html{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%}@font-face{font-family:Univers;src:url(6510377f-160a-4f66-aec0-2b71f05e9736.d3ac2084ab2be7590785.eot?#iefix);src:url(6510377f-160a-4f66-aec0-2b71f05e9736.d3ac2084ab2be7590785.eot?#iefix) format("eot"),url(5c8d59c2-9c85-4a22-88e3-bf3fba01dcd8.ddc403e80f5defea7e70.woff2) format("woff2"),url(fc51d03b-0d7d-45df-9415-3c6270c80749.41f238e7ce957020e8b6.woff) format("woff"),url(74bdff6d-c5de-42e8-a4d8-11ea14eddb22.9c84dba1a8863232e770.ttf) format("truetype")}*{box-sizing:border-box}body,html{height:100%;margin:0}body{background:linear-gradient(90deg,#f5f5f5 13%,#fff 0)}@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 991px){body{background:#fff}}@media (min-width: 991px) and (max-width: 1430px){body{background:linear-gradient(90deg,#f5f5f5 19%,#fff 0)}}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.db492d014ffa429c63e4.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.db492d014ffa429c63e4.css"></noscript></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.ff52d648e834c699a0b4.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.ff52d648e834c699a0b4.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.baf4cfee6c63995c3f95.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.2604048c091498279ad9.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.5c943bff49c01ee28e75.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.8840e97f4c6035599c4e.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.8840e97f4c6035599c4e.js" nomodule defer></script>

</body></html>
```

But when I launch from Bamboo (my Continuous Integration server) for deploy in the PROD environment, this is the "index.html" file that it generates:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyApp</title>
  <base href="//">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.d58008e01f99164b2da5.css"></head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
<script src="runtime-es2015.db34ebc8be30428ea01d.js" type="module"></script><script src="runtime-es5.db34ebc8be30428ea01d.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es5.d53252d4a10d8a12fd56.js" nomodule defer></script><script src="polyfills-es2015.9b66b8be828437ffc33a.js" type="module"></script><script src="scripts.5c943bff49c01ee28e75.js" defer></script><script src="main-es2015.7a52975a436dd20c744b.js" type="module"></script><script src="main-es5.7a52975a436dd20c744b.js" nomodule defer></script></body>
</html>
```

In the html tag "base" it stays empty it is not except the context of my application "myapp".

This is the instruction to launch the deploy command in my sh file/script:

```
npm --prefix src/myapp run build_PROD
```

What could be the problem?